# Bootstrap navbar dropdown menu/collapsed navbar not opening

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to add a navbar to this website, but for some reason it is not functioning how I thought it would. The main problem I am trying to solve is getting the dropdown menu to actually display the list. It visually looks like the menu is already expanded, but I don't know if that has anything to do with why it is not working. Currently, the collapsed version will open from the hamburger menu only because of the CSS I added. Without the CSS, that navbar will expand, but immediately collapse again. Things I have tried:

- I have tried to switch the order that I include Bootstrap.js/css and jQuery, but that has no effect on it.
- I have also tried to switch versions because I am not sure what is compatible with what, but that has not been successful.
- The one thing that did work was using an old version of bootstrap, but I would like to use 4.0 or higher if that is possible.

I would appreciate it is someone could help me figure out why this is not working. Thanks!

```css
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Title</title>


  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

   

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Products
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
  <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
  </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you using Bootstrap 3.3.7 **JS** with Bootstrap 4 **CSS**? You should use the same version js and css. In bootstrap 3 they used the class "in" and in 4 they use the class "show"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your `bootstrap.js` is version 3.3.7, and this is not how you implement sub-menu (on bootstrap 3). Although, If you're using bootstrap 4 already, you should consider updating your `bootstrap.js` to version 4.0.0 (And you should use the same versions of `bootstrap.js` and `bootstrap.css` to avoid unexepected bugs (like you just had).

```css
.navbar-collapse.collapse.in {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Title</title>


  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">

   

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Products
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1 class="display-3">Hello, world!</h1>
  <p class="lead">This is a simple hero unit, a simple jumbotron-style component for calling extra attention to featured content or information.</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p>It uses utility classes for typography and spacing to space content out within the larger container.</p>
  <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
  </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is correct, and to elaborate... Bootstrap 3 uses the class `in` to show and hide collapsing content (the js adds the class and the css has styles for that class). Bootstrap 4 uses the class `show` to show and hide collapsing content. So the version of Bootstrap js he had was adding the class `in`, but the css he was using for Bootstrap 4 did not have a style for `in` defined, which is why he had to create one. Bottom line **always use the same version js and css for Bootstrap**